# Cannot change theme dynamically

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the theme of an app dynamically. But I can change it only when the app is alive. Means, when I kill the app and open it again, the default theme is applied.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public ArrayList<FTPFile> listfile=null;
        Intent men;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("ThemePreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
            String choice=preferences.getString("CurrentTheme",null);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Its"+ choice,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           if(choice=="Light")
               this.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeLight);
           else
               this.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"

    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".file_explorer"  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".settings"  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
</application>
```

Code that changes value to shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("ThemePreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor=preferences.edit();
 RadioGroup rg=findViewById(R.id.radgrp);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId)
                {
                    case R.id.light:
                        Log.d("MRR","Light");
                        editor.putString("CurrentTheme","Light");
                        editor.apply();
                        break;
                    case R.id.dark:
                        Log.d("MRR","Dark");
                        editor.putString("CurrentTheme","Dark");
                        editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey,  may you please show the code you use to set the theme preference.

Comment: sure! i have added it .pls see

Comment: You need to call `recreate` after setting the theme so that the Activity can be rebuilt according to the new theme.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that changes the Theme in a new function outside of onCreate()/onStart()/onResume()

Example:

```
package ...;

import ..;

public class MainActivity(){
    protected void onCreate(){
        //...Your code...
    }
    protected void onStart(){
        //...Your code, if you have onStart()...
    }
    protected void onResume(){
        //...Your code, if you have onResume()...
    }
    changeTheme(int themeMode){
        //Add the code as I have told below
    }
}
```

Call the function when the radiobutton's state is changed by the ***user***.

(**This is important as the listener is called for the first time even if you don't change it manually**).

To check whether it was the user who changed it, and not the value in SharedPreferences, use onClickListener for the radio button instead of onCheckChangedListener.This way you know for sure the user has changed the value and not the value in SharedPreferences. Inside the OnClickListener, change the state of the radio button, to simulate the working of the radio button, and do the SharedPreferences value updation. This is just a workaround for the problem you have mentioned, do not use it if your app uses the radio button's state often to do other work, as these Listeners nested within themselves will take lot of space and CPU cycles.

Answer (score 0):

To implementing a dark/night theme, it's better to use the [darktheme](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/darktheme) feature.

The following code is a sample of its implementation:

```
 boolean isNight = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES

                viewModel.setThemeStatus(isNight) //save the last state of theme
                //to switch between light/dark
                AppCompatDelegate
               .setDefaultNightMode(isNight ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

And in your launcher activity:

```
boolean isNight = viewModel.getThemeStatus()

AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(isNight ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself!
I dont know how but I changed this

```
editor.putString("CurrentTheme","Light");
                        editor.apply();
```

to this,

```
editor.putBoolean("CurrentTheme",true);
                        editor.apply();
```